# gallery view on android in alertdialog

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have source code for a slider puzzle. it delivers a random image for the puzzle and you can change alot of settings like tiles and numbers and what not. Its really easy to add pictures you just have to have them start with image_ and put them in the drawable folder. Only thing is it does not have a layout.xml i guess everything is written through the activity.

I want to have all of the pictures in like a gallery view when a button is clicked in the menu. i have seen all the gallery codes need code in the layout which this source code does not have so essentially i would like

rather than this

```
public void showAbout()
{
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle(R.string.title_about);
    builder.setMessage(R.string.content_about);
    builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.label_ok, null);
    builder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    AlertDialog dlg = builder.create();
    dlg.show();
  ((TextView)         dlg.findViewById(android.R.id.message)).setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
}
```

i just want it to show up as a photo gallery

Comment: GalleryView has been deprecated since api level 16.  I would think twice about using it.

Comment: so how to i show a gallery?